# Log File For Selenium

Tags: selenium

Selenium got halt while running through jenkins. Not getting any idea where to debug the error.
Is there any log file to debug the selenium server.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working with selenium rc, You can generate a really good looking html log using LoggingSelenium.jar.

Refer This Link:

```
http://loggingselenium.sourceforge.net/usage.html
```